# How to remove textblock dynamically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    int margin = 200;
    public Window2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            TextBlock DynamicLine = new TextBlock();
            DynamicLine.Name = "lbl_DynamicLine" + i;
            DynamicLine.Width = 600;
            DynamicLine.Height = 20;
            DynamicLine.Text =i+"Dynamic TextBlock";
            DynamicLine.Margin = new Thickness(50, margin, 0, 0);
            margin = margin + 20;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(DynamicLine);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the textblock dynamically like below.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(DynamicLine);
```

But i can remove the last created textblock only with above code line.Now i want to remove all textblock dynamically. what should i do for that.

Comment: If you have dynamic content, i would not try to mess with wpf control functions, instead use WPFs actual support for dynamic content, like DataBinding, ObservableCollections, DataTemplates etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    int margin = 200;
    TextBlock DynamicLine;
    public Window2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            DynamicLine = new TextBlock();
            DynamicLine.Name = "lbl_DynamicLine" + i;
            RegisterName(DynamicLine.Name, DynamicLine);
            DynamicLine.Width = 600;
            DynamicLine.Height = 20;
            DynamicLine.Text =i+"Dynamic TextBlock";
            DynamicLine.Margin = new Thickness(50, margin, 0, 0);
            margin = margin + 20;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(DynamicLine);             

        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            DynamicLine = (TextBlock)this.FindName("lbl_DynamicLine" + i);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(DynamicLine);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all children, you should call the clear method.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: suppose already i had created a static textblock means,It will also delete by you code.

Comment: Hmm.. i dont quite understand. What do you mean by static? So you dont want to delete all textblocks, but only few? Based on what?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = LayoutRoot.Children.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
    LayoutRoot.Children.RemoveAt(i-1);
}
```